# Is it possible to use selenium to click this button?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click

The xpath is correct and I've tried both variations but it returns NoneType

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pyautogui

# Set up a webdriver instance using the Chrome browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Navigate to the staking page
driver.get('https://staking.chain.link/')

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(15)

# Find the "Next" button
next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/button[2]')

# Click the "Next" button to retrieve the next 10 results
next_button.click()
```

I want to be able to click through the table displaying the oracles answers. Is it possible to use Selenium to click this button?

I also tried:

```py
next_button = class_element= driver.find_element_by_class('button_secondary__WYcyn paragraph-100')
```

Comment: The `find_element_by_xpath` is deprecated in newer versions of Selenium, maybe that is why it doesn't work as intended. It works on my pc with these changes:

added this import
`from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

and modified this line
`next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/button[2]')`

Answer (score 1):

The find_element_by_xpath has been deprecated in newer versions of Selenium

add this import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

change this line

```
next_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/button[2]')
```

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/